# `integrate_1d` syntax and interactively debugging it

Tags: integration, stan, rstan

I am a first-time rstan/Stan user trying to set up a custom likelihood and integrate it using `integrate_1d`. Based on the [documentation](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_21/functions-reference/functions-1d-integrator.html), I set up my integrand function as follows:

```
// internal function to integrate over z 
// integrate_1d is super picky: the argument types need to be real, real, 
    real[], real[], int[]
// e.g., cannot use vectors in place of real[] or int[]

real integrand( real x,  // the observed Z-stat; value at which to evaluate integral
              real xc,
              real[] theta,
              real[] x_r,
              int[] x_i ){

    // separate the parameters
    real zeta = theta[1];
    real eta = theta[2];
    real vi = theta[3];

    // significance indicator
    int signif; 
    signif = fabs(x) > 1.96;

    return( (1/eta) * (1 - signif) + signif ) * exp( normal_lpdf( x | zeta, sqrt(vi) ) );
  }
```

I am trying to test and debug this function because it ultimately causes errors in evaluating the log-likelihood when I run my model. To this end, I want to be able to run the function interactively, passing arguments of my own choosing. I am trying to use rstan's `expose_stan_functions` to do this:

```
code = "functions{

  real integrand( real x,  // the observed Z-stat
                  real xc,
                  real[] theta,
                  real[] x_r,
                  int[] x_i ){

    // separate the parameters
    real zeta = theta[1];
    real eta = theta[2];
    real vi = theta[3];

    // significance indicator
    int signif; 
    signif = fabs(x) > 1.96;

    return( (1/eta) * (1 - signif) + signif ) * exp( normal_lpdf( x | zeta, sqrt(vi) ) );
  }
}"

expose_stan_functions(stanc(model_code = code))

integrand(1, {1,1,1}, real[], int[], 1e-8)

integrate_1d( integrand, negative_infinity(), positive_infinity(), {1, 1, 1}, real[], int[], 1e-8 )
```

but the calls to `integrand` and `integrate_1d` each throw error

> Error: unexpected ','

as if I am calling the functions with fundamentally incorrect syntax. (In the call to `integrate_1d`, I wasn't quite sure what to do about `xc`. I omitted it because the documentation (Section 9.3.2.4) seems to suggest it should be `NaN` for an indefinite integral.)

I also welcome completely different suggestions for interactively debugging `integrand` if `expose_stan_functions` is not the ideal way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `integrate_1d` function is a Stan / C++ function, so if you want to call it from R, you need to specify another function that calls it. In your case, you could do

```
code = "functions{

  real integrand( real x,  // the observed Z-stat
                  real xc,
                  real[] theta,
                  real[] x_r,
                  int[] x_i ){

    // separate the parameters
    real zeta = theta[1];
    real eta = theta[2];
    real vi = theta[3];

    // significance indicator
    int signif; 
    signif = fabs(x) > 1.96;

    return( (1/eta) * (1 - signif) + signif ) * exp( normal_lpdf( x | zeta, sqrt(vi) ) );
  }

  real area(real[] theta, data real[] x_r) {
    int x_i[0];
    return integrate_1d(integrand, negative_infinity(), positive_infinity(),
                        theta, x_r, x_i, 1e-8);
  }
}"

library(rstan)
expose_stan_functions(stanc(model_code = code))
area(theta = rep(1, 3), x_r = double()) # yields 1
```

Comment: This works great. Two questions: (1) Since `area` is also a Stan function, why is it that R is able to call this one, using its own data types (e.g., a vector for theta instead of a real array), even though it can't call `integrate_1d` directly? (2) What does `data` in the declaration `data real[]` mean? I couldn't seem to Google this effectively.

Comment: An expression used as an argument marked `data` cannot contain any parameters, transformed parameters, or local variables from the transformed parameters or model blocks.  The other way around, it can only contain data variables, transformed data variables, or local variables in the transformed data block.  It can also be used with generated quantities. For the `map_rect` function, parallel execution also won't work if local variables are used in `data` arguments.

Comment: I don't believe there is an `area` function in the Stan Math library already; otherwise the parser would have thrown an error about duplicate symbols. When you call `rstan::expose_stan_functions`, R wrapper functions are created that call the C++ functions of the same name.